# Aggregating colliding nodes in d3.js after certain simulation time

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I have a d3 simulation that groups nodes dependent on their properties, as calculated by an algorithm. Upon a number of iterations of this algorithm, I want to be able to display a 'cluster area' around certain groups, preferably through aggregating collided nodes while the algorithm is still running. So, rather than taking the approach of [this block](https://bl.ocks.org/Fil/10a29cd5074cad3f04522c77f1c1c3c4), where nodes are removed upon collision, is it possible to aggregate a count of collided nodes? And perhaps in a different way than noted in that block (seems to be computationally expensive with hundreds of data nodes)? I've looked through documentation for d3-force and couldn't find anything that struck out.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried D3's k-means clustering? It doesn't merge nodes. http://bl.ocks.org/feyderm/75c18a9143aac50a24e392762f10d6a4

Comment: @VictorStoddard Thanks for the reference! I ended up using a different method to represent aggregated nodes but this set me on the right track.